# Primefaces Implementing valueChangeListener along with confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu on my page which is set to execute some action onChange. I want to show a confirmDialog before the action is executed.

Below is my implementation for it but doesn't seem to work. The confirm dialog gets hidden automatically without giving the user time to select an option and the quest contains the value from previous selection.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{component.selectedAction}"onchange="confirmDialogWidgetVar.show()" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option A" itemValue="A"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option B" itemValue="B"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option C" itemValue="C"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option D" itemValue="D"/>
    <p:ajax update="confirmDialog" process="@this" global="false"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" widgetVar="confirmDialogWidgetVar" message="Are you sure you want to select #{component.selectedAction}?">
    <p:commandButton value="YES" oncomplete="confirmDialogWidgetVar.hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="NO" onclick="confirmDialogWidgetVar.hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

The message I want show is "Are you sure you want to select Option A?" in the confirm dialog when option A is selected.

Comment: I see you open the dialog, send the AJAX request to update that dialog, which is hidden after the update is finished. You should open the dialog when the p:ajax complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it's working fine now

```
    public void check(){
    System.out.println(""+getSelectedAction());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("confirmDialogWidgetVar.show()");
    }

    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{home.selectedAction}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option A" itemValue="A"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option B" itemValue="B"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option C" itemValue="C"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option D" itemValue="D"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{home.check}" />
    <f:ajax render="confirmDialog" ></f:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>


    <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" widgetVar="confirmDialogWidgetVar"   message="Are you sure you want to select#{home.selectedAction}?">`
    <p:commandButton value="YES" oncomplete="confirmDialogWidgetVar.hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="NO" onclick="confirmDialogWidgetVar.hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Please describe and explain the solution in words as well instead of making it a seek&find game by showing only the code.

Comment: Ok I will make sure from here onwards.

Answer (score 0):

This might be tricky to do using `p:dialog`. The problems are:

1) the dialog message uses a managed bean which gets updated AFTER the selectMenu value is changed -> that's why you see the old value

2) showing the dialog does not blok the change ajax event, so the selectMenu gets updated regardless of the dialog commands

One way of doing this is to use [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361742/how-to-prevent-to-change-selectbox-value-if-i-say-no-to-confirm).

If you want to do this using primefaces and jsf components only, I'm afraid you'll end up with a server round trip. The idea is: bind the selectMenu to a proxy field like `component.selectedActionProxy` and add an action to the `<p:command value="YES"` which basically does this: `component.selectedAction = component.selectedActionProxy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your functionality by this way.
Create `private boolean check;` in backing bean, and check if the value and proceed as per your wish as shown below.

```
<h:form id="form">

        <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{buttonBean.emp.number}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        <p:ajax listener="#{buttonBean.change}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>      




 <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure about destroying the world?"  
                header="Initiating destroy process" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">  

        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" actionListener="#{buttonBean.dialogCheck}" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" update="@form" 
                     />  
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />   

    </p:confirmDialog>

        </h:form>
```

//Backing bean

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class ButtonBean implements Serializable{



        private Employee emp;;
        private boolean check;;

        public void change(){

            System.out.println("open dilaog box on value change------");


            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("confirmation.show()");



        }


        public void dialogCheck(){

            check=true;

           if(emp.getNumber().equals("1") && check==true){

            System.out.println("do your change--here-");

        }

        }


        public Employee getEmp() {

            if(emp==null){

                emp=new Employee();
            }

            return emp;
        }


        public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
            this.emp = emp;
        }


        public boolean isCheck() {
            return check;
        }


        public void setCheck(boolean check) {
            this.check = check;
        }





    }
```